# Google javascript API library - Calendar watch notifications

Tags: javascript, calendar, google-api

I am trying to subscribe to calendar event notifications with the JS client library like this:

```
gapi.client.load('calendar', 'v3', function () {
            var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.watch({
                'calendarId': cl.gCalendarID,
                'id': unid,
                'type': "web_hook",
                'address': {my url here}
            });
            request.execute(function (resp) {
                console.log(resp);
            });
        });
```

But I just keep getting 400 returned with an unhelpful message of "`Entity.Resource`"

In the data object of the response I get `Domain:global, Message: Entity.Resource, reason: Required"`

I am authenticated already with oauth2 and I have granted access with my Google account and I can successfully retrieve the list of calendars and I am retrieving events from them calendars but this method to subscribe to the watch will not work? Please help I can't find anything on Google about this.

Comment: Do you know what your request's content-type is? I've seen this error when it was != application/json

Answer (score 7):

```
Instead of this:


 var request = gapi.client.calendar.events.watch({
                'calendarId': cl.gCalendarID,
                'id': unid,
                'type': "web_hook",
                'address': {my url here}
            });
```

You Use this syntax:

```
calendar.events.watch({
            auth: auth,
                resource: {
                    id: "12345",
                    type: 'web_hook',
                    address: {mu url here}
                 },
                calendarId: 'primary' 

            }, function(err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    logger.MessageQueueLog.log("info","index.js:- watchnotification(),Error in Watch Notification: " + err);

                } else {          
                   logger.MessageQueueLog.log("info","index.js:- watchnotification(), Notification : " + JSON.stringify(response));           

                }
            });
```

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the token value in the request made to the Calendar API, to distinguish your requests from each other as below

```
{
  "id": string,
  "token": string,
  "type": string,
  "address": string,
  "params": {
  "ttl": string
 }
}
```

For further reference, please refer to

[Google Calendar API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/watch)

Comment: This did not help me. Token is optional.