# Google Calendar Push Api Node Not Working? [entity.resource] [watch]

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-calendar-api

Heres my code:

```
var google = googleapis;
var OAuth2 = google.auth.OAuth2;
var oauth2Client = new OAuth2('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxxx', 'https://bt-feedback.meteor.com/oauth2');
oauth2Client.setCredentials({
  access_token: 'xxxxxxxx',
  refresh_token: 'xxxxxxxx'
});
google.options({ auth: oauth2Client }); // set auth as a global default

var calendar = google.calendar('v3');

calendar.events.watch({ 
    calendarId: 'xxxxxxxxxxx'
}, 
{
    id: 'xxx-xx-xx-xx-xxxxxxxxxx',
    address: 'https://bt-feedback.meteor.com/notifications',
    type: 'web_hook'
}, function(err, res) {
    console.log("err, res:", err, res);
});
```

Here's the error I keep getting:

```
W20150128-16:12:24.574(-7)? (STDERR) { errors: 
W20150128-16:12:24.576(-7)? (STDERR)    [ { domain: 'global',
W20150128-16:12:24.576(-7)? (STDERR)        reason: 'required',
W20150128-16:12:24.576(-7)? (STDERR)        message: 'entity.resource' } ],
W20150128-16:12:24.576(-7)? (STDERR)   code: 400,
W20150128-16:12:24.576(-7)? (STDERR)   message: 'entity.resource' }
```

Any idea whats up!? I checked out a bunch of diff questions but none of them seem to help any.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I didn't have time to figure out why the googleapis module isn't working on this point, but I got a direct API request working.

```
request.post('https://www.googleapis.com/calendar/v3/calendars/[calendarName]/events/watch',{
headers:{
    Authorization:'Bearer '+oauth2Client.credentials.access_token
    ,'content-type':'application/json'
}
,json:true
,body:{
    id:[channelId]
    ,type:'web_hook'
    ,address:[callbackUrl]
}},callback);
```

Comment: Wow, that's so annoying. But totally made my app work as well! Thanks!

Comment: Here you can find a correct answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35742629/329879

Basically when you specify options object it must have 'resource' (watch params) and 'calendarId' objects as props.